# php REST - prevent direct access in browser

Tags: php, rest, .htaccess, api

I'm developing REST API server in PHP, which I plan to call by client application, but I want to prevent direct API accesss via browser.

E.g. say I have GET call on "HOST/api/article/id" which would return article with given id to the client application. But when I type "HOST/api/article/id" in my browser, the article shouldn't be returned - I want nothing to happen (for example just return empty page or 403).

- **Is this possible?**
- **If yes, is it common practice?** (I mean is it something one would normally want to do or is it obscure and/or violates HTTP/REST principles and should be avoided?)
- **If yes, how do I do it?** (in PHP/.htaccess/etc.)

I know I could implement some kind of authorization (like API key) instead which would allow API execution only for the client applications, which I plan to do anyway.

(I'm kind of new to this so maybe my question doesn't make sense. Maybe I misunderstood something very basic about how REST/HTTP/whatever works. If so, please tell me.)

Comment: Have you tried something like `if( count(get_included_files()) == 1 )
 exit("Error, Contact Administrator");`
on the php file they're trying to access?

Comment: this might be worth a read. Get the server to enforce client authentication via certificates and only allow access if one is on the wire. Browsers don't generally send them https://cweiske.de/tagebuch/ssl-client-certificates.htm

Comment: @codebrane thanks, I'll give it a read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal approach would be:

1. Your client (using a public key), requests token from the server, token checks if key is valid and not blacklisted (you can expire/blacklist old keys if they are compromised)
2. Token is sent every time
3. Server only responds if there is a token

Depending what your requirements, there is a hacky way to implement this.

1. Have a variable, called "my_client" with value true
2. On each request from your application sent the variable in your headers.
3. Server only servers information if "my_client" variable is in the headers

The cons with this approach is, that is not really secure, because each person can see the requests they make. Therefor can notice this extra information.

Its so simple that you can write it for a minute, just as a test.

```
<?php
 if(!$_SERVER['HTTP_MY_CLIENT']){
   header("HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDEN");
  }
```

Extending on the concept of using a header variable, we can use it as "semi token", which will mean we will populate the value with a random value that only we can read.

So the concept is this:

Client -> Request random value
Client /sets value in each request header/
Client -> makes requests to the server.

```
<?php
 /* A basic API token and authentication class. */
 class SimpleToken
 {
    /* Creates a salt based on the passed key that is good for the current day */
   public static function generateSalt($key)
   {
    return md5($key . date('Y-m-d'));
   }
  /* Crytographically combine the key and the salt to produce a token */
   public static function generateToken($key, $content)
   {
    $package = $content . $key;
    return crypt($package);
   }
   /* Generate a relatively strong SSL key */
  public static function generateKey()
   {
    $config = array(
        "digest_alg" => "sha512",
        "private_key_bits" => 4096,
        "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
    );
    //Create a private key
    $res = openssl_pkey_new($config);
    //Extract the private part of the key
    openssl_pkey_export($res, $private_key);
    //Shorten it up for use in an API
    return md5($private_key);
}

/* Verify the authenticity of the passed key/token pair */
public static function isAuthentic($key, $content, $token)
{
    $package = $content . $key;
    if(crypt($package, $token) == $token)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't need cutting-edge security, there will not be any personal or critical data. It's just my side-project for fun. Even then, your hacky way seems not secure enough. I guess I'll try the first approach and see where it goes.

Comment: @awa993 1 way you can improve the hacky way is to use the value of the header variable, and insert there something generate by the server, which on firther calls you can validate :)

Comment: Maybe it will be just enough what I need. Like I said, I don't need much security. Although my server site will be public (what a surprise since it will be hanging on the internet), I will share it only with few friends.

Comment: @awa993 I have extended the answer with a class that can generate and validate random string, that you can use :) P.S. If this answer, helps you and answers your question can you mark it as accepted answer

Comment: Thank you for the code example. I might just go with just that for now & later see if it's enough.